# Geocoding with World Geocode Service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I failed to geocode intersection in ArcMap with World Geocode Service provided by ArcGIS Online. The data I have contains street, cross street, city, state. But there is no zipcode

Here is a sample record. The street name here is a combination of street and cross street:

Street: Research Blvd @ Spicewood Springs Blvd

City:   Austin

Region: Texas

Country: US

The weird thing is Geosearch Services can correctly find the address "Research Blvd @ Spicewood Springs Blvd, Austin, Texas, US". But if I try to use the Geocoding Services, it failed. All the addresses in Austin are converted into the same x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a long phone call with the technician at ERIS. Partly solved the issue. The problem is caused by the field name, which should be a bug of ArcGIS itself because the field name doesn't contain any reserved words or anything. Anyway, I successfully geocoded the data after changing the field name.

Comment: Do you have a bug number and description from Esri?